# my navigation in mobile is pushing down to two lines but on desktop its fine

Tags: html, css, web

So I have a website:

http://joekilgallon.com/

and everything looks fine on desktop but on my iphone the navigation pushes down to two lines. I know it has to do with the padding on my CSS for those links but I tried to change it but nothing is working without messing up desktop view. Can anyone help me figure how to change just mobile view or how to tweak my CSS to make the nav only on one line.

Comment: Please read:http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 0):

How about using some media queries! Where you can target certain screen sizes with specific css! check this out [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)!

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}
```

Comment: Totally worked, I knew about media queries but was thinking since it was a drupal installation css it would not get applied. thank you

Comment: You are welcome! Would you be so kind as to accept my answer as your solution? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work -Info Here